Extracting estimated birth year from German/West Prussian marriage record 1792
I have a marriage record (West Prussian, 1792) where the Ancestry estimated birth year for the bride is 1767. I think this is based on the translation of the groom's age and brides age being the same, on the right hand column, but I can't work out what it says. The best candidate I have for the bride is born in 1770 (Christina Schroedter, daughter of David Schroedter, b Langenau). Is there any way this has been mis-transcribed on the Ancestry record based on the image provided?



The image clip (marriage records, not birth records) shows 2 ages for the previous entry, but the 2nd age for the full entry you are interested in is very faded. Using the better zoom capability on the full image at ancestry, I think the bride's age may be 22y, but I'm not sure. You'll need to find a better image of the same page. FamilySearch has the collection but the image (also indexed as 25y) is not viewable online.

Thanks - you're right, it's very faded even zoomed (added).
